# Minimum depth of a binary tree

Tags: python, binary-tree

I'm trying to write code to find the minimum depth of a binary tree.
https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-depth-of-binary-tree/

```py
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution(object):
        
    def minDepth(self, node):
        if node is None:
            return 0
    
        else :
            # Compute the depth of each subtree
            lDepth = self.minDepth(node.left)
            rDepth = self.minDepth(node.right)
            return min(lDepth, rDepth) + 1
```

However, this solution does not work on some test cases, such as a highly unbalanced binary tree, which devolves to a linked list (ex `[2, None, 3, None, 4, None, 5, None, 6]`

The minimum depth is 5 (as None children do not count.) However, my solution returns 1, so it must be treating the left child of 2 as the minimum depth leaf node.

```
     2
    / \
       3
      / \
         4
        / \
           5
          / \
             6
```

I'm at a loss, why does this solution not adequately address this use case?

Comment: You might want to try using [`breakpoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint), add it as a new line inside your function and run it, it will stop its execution at that line and you'll be able to type into your terminal the names of your variables or use different commands to step through your code

Comment: consider: the minimum depth is not five. The *maximum* depth is five.

Comment: @KellyBundy You're not wrong. My point is that this definition is likely what is confusing them. Calling what they want to get the *maximum* depth instead would likely clear that confusion

Comment: @j1-lee Why? I may be missing something, but on a first glance it looks to me like all that is wrong is that `min()` should be `max()` in the code

Comment: Ohh. Okay, I take everything back. Thanks for calling me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Avinash, thanks for ID'ing the edge case.
And the problem @kellyBundy https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-depth-of-binary-tree/submissions/

```py
class Solution(object):
    
    def minDepth(self, node):
        # no node (dead branch)
        if node is None:
            return 0
        
        lDepth = self.minDepth(node.left)
        rDepth = self.minDepth(node.right)        
        
        if node.left and node.right: 
            return min(lDepth, rDepth) + 1
        
        else: #prevents counting first dead branch as minDepth
            return max(lDepth, rDepth) + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I think its because of the `min` function. Starting from 2, your code checks the left which is 0, then checks right which is recursively checked and returns 4. However, you call `min(0, 4)+1` which gives you an output of `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code stops recursion on `None` which is not a `TreeNode`, obviously, the term "depth" is undefined for such objects. Try to stop your recursion on so-called "leafs": nodes without children. Check out my solution for this problem:

```py
def is_leaf(node: TreeNode):
    return node.left is None and node.right is None

def min_depth(root: TreeNode):
    if is_leaf(root):
        return 1
    not_none_children = (
        child if child is not None
        for child in (root.left, root.right)]
    )
    return min(min_depth(child) for child in not_none_children) + 1
```